# Can I create an alias for an entire namespace in PHP?

Tags: php, composer-php

Can I create a namespace alias using PHP 8.1 functions such as [class alias](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php)?

We named the default namespace module in our company as "Subcompany" and want it to become "Company" now, as it's use has been broadened.

A perfect answer would as little as possible overhead and also allow autoloading transparently. A concern is that tools such as [Intelephense](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense) would understand this alias.

The project also uses composer, so an answer that rewrites namespaces using that would work too.

Comment: You can [alias namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) but you'd have to edit every file where it's used, and if you're going to do that, you might as well just change the namespace. I'd just do a recursive `sed` and mass-edit the old to the new.

Comment: Rewrite the namespace over the weekend and on Monday everyone can continue with the new namespace. This also prevents you from aliases scattering the application and no one wants to touch it later on.

Comment: @hakre we were forced to move on with the old namespace some months ago and now a few applications are using it. I might write a sed script of sorts that I can share with other team members so they can update their projects too. It will take more than one weekend to do it safely sadly!

Comment: @hawaii: I've added an answer which may help on how to migrate from old to new with `class_alias()` and `spl_autoload_register()` in a more on-the-fly way. Another alternative is to pre-generate the aliases from the classmap of the new and old classes/interfaces/traits/enums (e.g. let composer build the classmap, then parse it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I create a namespace alias using PHP 8.1 functions such as class alias?

Yes, and thinking: [`class_alias`](https://www.php.net/class_alias) was introduced with PHP 5.3 and its' new namespaces language feature. It has been created so that it is easier to migrate from the global namespace into namespaces - which actually *is* between namespaces.

However you would need to register a class alias for every old classes/interfaces/traits/enums to their new counterpart first.

```
My\Old\Lib\Name\Module\Submodule\Interface
My\Tiger\Lib\Name\Module\Submodule\Interface
```

The old lib is gone, and there now is the brand new Tiger lib.  All their classes etc. can be mapped by just exchanging the namespace prefix (`'My\Old\Lib\Name\' -> 'My\Tiger\Lib\Name'`).

This can done done at runtime already as PHP does most of the work for you.

Register an autoloader, that based on the old namespace prefix loads as the new namespace prefix *and* aliasing the class to the old name beforehand.

Example:

```php
spl_autoload_register(
    static function (string $class_name) {
        static $old = 'My\\Old\\Lib\\Name\\';
        static $new = 'My\\Tiger\\Lib\\Name\\';

        // only operate on the old namespace
        if (0 !== strpos($class_name, $old)) {
            return;
        }
        $new_name = substr_replace($class_name, $new, 0, strlen($old));
        class_alias($new_name, $class_name);
        $exists = class_exists($new_name);
    },
    $throw = true,   /* throw when registering fails */
    $prepend = false /* only alias at fall-through */
);
```

This code is straight forward, just two remarks on the registration parameters:

1. `$throw = true`: You want to stop your application immediately when the aliasing autoloader can not be registered as otherwise you would get strange "class not found" errors much much later.
2. `$prepend = false`: Only if there still is code that is using the old classnames, the callback should be invoked. The now standard code using the new namespace with standard autoloading therefore comes first.

And perhaps noteworthy is the `class_exists()` part:

```php
        $exists = class_exists($new_name);
```

it triggers the autoloading for the new class if it has not yet been loaded.

> Tip: Use an assertive variant of it so that within development it throws where there is still code using the old namespace. Then you can gather information while migrating in a more planned manner:
>
> ```php
>             ...
>             $new_name = substr_replace($class_name, $new, 0, strlen($old));
>             assert(false, "old namespace in use: $class_name");
>             class_alias($new_name, $class_name);
>             $exists = class_exists($new_name);
>             assert($exists, "aliasing old namespace failed for class: $class_name");
>         },
>         ...
> ```
>
> (developers should have throwing assertions enabled, not the production setting in which assertions are completely ignored)

Once the autoloader is registered, old code will automagically load the new classes under the old alias.

```php
use My\Old\Lib\Name\Module\Boring;

$boring = new Boring();
assert($boring instanceof My\Old\Lib\Name\Module\Boring);
var_dump(get_class($boring)); # string(31) "My\Tiger\Lib\Name\Module\Boring"
```

- [Full example on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/k2SDE).

Comment: ill try this out asap!!! thanks for your effort

Comment: @hawaii you're welcome. let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: we've assigned another dev to tackle this. After he clears his schedule, we will do this. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: ive finally was able to sit and work it out. It worked great for general use except when using reflections. Since I was struggling with that, I decided to go and replace the references to the name namespace. An example was: querying attributes (reflectionMethod->getAttributes) that inherited from Tiger\Attrib, but old code had it with Old\Attrib; Nevertheless ill just accept your answer as the correct one now. It really helped!